# Custom photo caption when uploading a picture using Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook App that allows users to upload pictures from my website to my Facebook page. I would like to know who uploaded the pictures and after some research I managed to get this following PHP code:

```
$args = array(
   'message' => $fbme['name'].' will have a love marriage.',
   'image'   => '@' . realpath('./images/wall-e-and-eva1.jpg'),

);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/photos', 'post', $args);
```

My output is suppose to be on the lines of *Adam Smith will have a love marriage* unfortunately the only output I am getting is  *will have a love marriage*.

How can I get the value of $fbme['name'] - can you give me a pratical example of code please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph api to fetch basic information (including name) of your authenticated users

```
try {
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/'.$uid); // $fbme['name'] will be the user's name
    // put rest of your code below
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // handle errors
}
```

Comment: When I insert your code and do this   $args = array(
   'message' =>  $fbme['name'],
   'image' => '@' . $img,

I get 'null' as a comment.

Comment: Sound like the that the sdk is not authenticated as an user, maybe its an app auth? You try replacing the "/me" with the $uid variable, that should avoid the problem when "me" is not the same as the user who you are posting to. I've upadted the example.

Comment: I changed the code with your edited code and still the same. It is giving me null.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but it's possible that you have the `$fbme` variable defined somewhere in your code after the newly inserted one and before issuing the `$args = array()` part, since its included in your original snippet, as `$facebook` or `$uid`.

Comment: I do not have $fbme defined... Can I contact you on email and send you all my code please?

Comment: You can write me <my username here>@gmail.com